# Create multiple branches from Jira

Tags: automation, bitbucket, jira

I need to automatically create multiple branches on a Bitbucket repo when a developer creates a branch from a Jira Issue.
The branching pattern is this:

feature/SAx

feature/SAx-FE

feature/SAx-BE

So I would need to automatically create the feature/SAx branch and then split this new branch into the FE and BE branches.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Git itself will create a branch when you tell it to, so if you need to create three branches, tell Git to create three branches, and you're done. How you get some sort of *automation* for this using Jira is a Jira and/or automation question, not a Git one. You might also have a (separate) bitbucket API question; for that, see the [tag:bitbucket-api] tag.